# MobX full recompute on read though observables don't change?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have a mobx store that looks like

```
class EntityStore {
  rootStore
  @observable entityIndex = {}
  constructor(rootStore){
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }

  @action addEntities(entityArray){
    entityArray.forEach((entity) => this.addEntity(entity));
  }

  @action addEntity(entityProps){
    if(entityProps.id && this.entityIndex[entityProps.id]){
      throw new Error(`Failed to add ${entityProps.id} an entity with that id already exists`);
    }

    const entity = new Entity({
      ...entityProps,
      assetStore: this.rootStore.assetStore,
      regl,
    });
    this.entityIndex[entity.id] = entity;
  }

  @computed get entityAssetIds(){
    return Object.values(this.entityIndex).map(e => e.assetId);
  }

  @computed get renderPayload(){
    const payloadArray = [];
    for(let entityId in this.entityIndex){
      payloadArray.push(this.entityIndex[entityId].renderPayload)
    }
    return payloadArray;
  }
}
```

This is an expensive computed value with child computed values that gets called in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop that calls `entityStore.renderPayload()` at 60fps. I need this to be cached.

using `trace` i've got output of
`[mobx.trace] 'EntityStore@1.renderPayload' is being read outside a reactive context. Doing a full recompute`

This is surprising to me as my expectations were Mobx would only recompute if the dependent observables to the computed value changed.

Is there any way force this non-recompute behavior?

**Update**: I am not using react. this is Plain mobx objects
I have created a reproduction example at https://github.com/kevzettler/mobx_bad/ 
it looks like

```
class ShouldMemoize {
  @observable position = 0
  staticValue = 200;

  @computed get expensiveStaticOperation(){
    console.log('this is expensive and should not recompute');
    return this.staticValue*2;
  }

  @computed get output(){
    return this.position + this.expensiveStaticOperation;
  }

  @action incrementPosition(val){
    this.position+= 1;
  }
}


let M = new ShouldMemoize();
console.log('**********start*********');
setInterval(() =>{
  M.incrementPosition();
  console.log(
    "*tick*",
    M.output
  );
}, 60)
```

This example demonstrates a computed method `expensiveStaticOperation` that is referenced from another computed method `output`. the `output` method is called at a rapid interval and the log output indicates that `expensiveStaticOperation` is then called as well and recomputed on each tick. I would expect that because the dependent values of `expensiveStaticOperation` do not change that it would be memoized and not re executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually the behaviour seen when you attempt to access the value without using an `observer` (or `reaction`, or `autorun`). You don't mention whether you're using React, or another library, or explain how you're accessing the value. It may be worth setting up a minimal example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or similar that reproduces the problem you're seeing.

If I had to speculate, I'd say you're consuming your computed value somewhere in a component that isn't wrapped with `observer` (in the case of React). [Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/mobx-use-computed-outside-reaction-god8v?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14) an example (with unused methods removed) that reproduces the problem with no additional framework:

```js
import { autorun, computed, configure, observable } from "mobx";

class EntityStore {
  @observable entityIndex = {};

  @computed get renderPayload() {
    const payloadArray = [];
    for (let entityId in this.entityIndex) {
      payloadArray.push(this.entityIndex[entityId].renderPayload);
    }
    return payloadArray;
  }
}
configure({ computedRequiresReaction: true });

const store = new EntityStore();

// console.log('THIS WILL TRIGGER A WARNING:', store.renderPayload)

autorun(() => console.log('THIS WILL NOT TRIGGER A WARNING:', store.renderPayload))
```

If you uncomment the log, you should see a console warning. Chances are, you're consuming the computed value somewhere that isn't inside `observer` or similar. If you're sure this isn't the case, maybe add some more detail to the question.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post a complete, minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I have added a minimal example and bounty

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to take another look in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Mobx isn't bad like you named it in repo with example, instead it is so awesome that it doesn't recompute those values that are not observed by any code.

To fix your example, just put this one line before `setInterval`

```
observe(M, 'output', () => {})
```

Now MobX knows that output is observed and your expensive computation will run only once. Until some related variable changes.

Just do observe on used computed fields before starting animation loop and do dispose after end, it will work like a charm.